# Share and update docker data containers across containers

Tags: docker, containers

I have the following containers:

- Data container which is build directly in quay.io from a github repo, basically is a website.
- FPM container
- NGINX container

The three of them are linked together and working just fine. BUT the problem is that every time I change something in the website (Data container) it is rebuilt (of course) and I have to remove that container and also the FPM and NGINX and recreate them all to be able to read the new content.

I started with a "backup approach" for what I'm copying the data from the container to a host directory and mounting that into the FPM and NGINX containers, this way I can update the data without restarting/removing any service.

But the idea of moving the data from the data container into the host, really doesn't like me. So wondering if there a "docker way" or a better way of doing it.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Adding more context

Dockerfile d`ata container definition

```
FROM debian

ADD data/* /home/mustela/

VOLUME /home/mustela/
```

Where `data` only has 2 files: `hello.1` and `hello.2`

Compiling the image:

`docker build -t="mustela/data" .`

Running the data container:

`docker run --name mustela-data mustela/data`

Creating another container to link to the previous one:

`docker run -d -it --name nginx --volumes-from mustela-data ubuntu bash`

Listing the mounted files:

`docker exec -it nginx ls /mustela/home`

Result:

`hello.1  hello.2`

Now, lets rebuild the data container image, but first adding some new files, so now inside `data` we have `hello.1  hello.2  hello.3  hello.4`

```
docker rm mustela-data
docker build -t="mustela/data" .
docker run --name mustela-data mustela/data
```

If I `ls /home/mustela` from the running container, the files aren't being updated:

`docker exec -it nginx ls /mustela/home`

Result:

`hello.1  hello.2`

But if I run a new container I can see the files

`docker run -it --name nginx2 --volumes-from mustela-data ubuntu ls /home/mustela`

Result: `hello.1  hello.2  hello.3  hello.4`

Comment: Can't you simply mount volumes from old data container onto the new data container and thus avoid dumping the data onto the host?

Comment: @MykolaGurov I'm doing that, but when I rebuild the data container I need to remove it and create it again to have the new code. But the other containers don't see that changes unless I remove then and create again

Comment: Meaning that you don't have true data containers if you still have code within. If you split your "data container" into the true data container, which purpose is to host data volumes, and the rest (sources of your site and such), then the bare data container can survive the rebuild. As per [example](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)

Comment: @MykolaGurov I just updated the question with more information